# TYPO3 10: XOAUTH2 for SMTP fails with Office365

Tags: office365, typo3-10.x

I send mails via a contact form (typo3 forms) with Office365, and it's no longer working:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "contact@my-office-mail.com" using the following authenticators: "LOGIN", "XOAUTH2". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got an empty response.". Authenticator "XOAUTH2" returned "Expected response code "235" but got an empty response.". | Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\TransportException thrown in file /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/mailer/Transport/Smtp/EsmtpTransport.php in line 189. Requested URL: http://my-typo3.com/de/kontakt?tx_form_formframework%%5Baction%%5D=perform&tx_form_formframework%%5Bcontroller%%5D=FormFrontend&cHash=f9feb685a5b827a2b8c557dd41598b64
```

The error message from "Test Mail Setup":

```
Could not deliver mail
Please verify $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['MAIL'][*] settings are valid. Error message: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "contact@my-office-mail.com" using the following authenticators: "LOGIN", "XOAUTH2". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got an empty response.". Authenticator "XOAUTH2" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator. [xx.xx.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]".".
```

My configuration:

```php
'MAIL' => [
        'defaultMailFromAddress' => 'contact@my-office-mail.com',
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'transport_sendmail_command' => '',
        'transport_smtp_encrypt' => false,
        'transport_smtp_password' => 'supergr8password',
        'transport_smtp_server' => 'smtp.office365.com',
        'transport_smtp_username' => 'contact@my-office-mail.com',
    ]
```

I think the old configuration no longer works due to the changeover from Office365, but there is nothing about this in the Mail API documentation.

Comment: TYPO3 uses `symfony/mailer` for sending mails and symfony/mailer supports XOAUTH2 https://github.com/symfony/mailer/blob/6.2/Transport/Smtp/Auth/XOAuth2Authenticator.php TYPO3 should handle this too. I also try to get this working in my TYPO3 setup.